# JavaScript не работает часть кода на странице

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, пытался добавить социальные кнопки на главную страницу сайта [www.travianx5.ru/](http://www.travianx5.ru/), вот код, который я добавил

```
<div class="share42init"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.travianx5.ru/share42/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.travianx5.ru/share42/share42.js"></script>
```

Почему после добавления этого кода перестает работать весь другой javascript, который находиться на странице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на сайте используется Mootools, который использует переменную $ по-своему. Подключая jQuery, эта переменная переопределяется.

Попробуйте использовать [jQuery.noConflict()](http://jdevelop.info/articles/9-develop-joomla/99-jquery-with-mootools)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что jquery переопределяет функцию `$`, которая была определена ранее в mt-core.js. Кроме того, загляните в консоль, там куча ошибок.